# Behavior of strcmp appears to be weird during inter-process communication using sockets

Tags: c, sockets, strcmp

I wrote a program in which I used to scan a string and a keyword from the user and return the number of occurrences of that keyword in the string. I used `strcmp` function after splitting the input string on white spaces and it worked fine.

Now, I am trying to do the same work using IPC with sockets where the client inputs the strings and keywords, and the server does the counting work. But in this case, I am not getting the same results for the same input. I looked at the return values of strcmp and found that it is returning non-zero values even when the input strings appear same to me.

What could be the cause & how can I resolve it?

Here is the code for server.
Reference: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //
    char * input;
    char * str;
    char * word;
    int i, wordLen, strLen;
    char terminator = ';';
    char * pch;
    char * new;
    int temp, count = 0;
    //
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[36];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     bzero(buffer,36);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,35);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     //
     input = (char *) malloc(36);
     strcpy(input, buffer);
     word = strchr(input, terminator);
     temp = (strlen(input) - strlen(word));
     str = (char *) malloc(temp);
     //strlcpy(str, input, temp);
     *str = '\0'; 
     strncat(str, input, temp);
     word++;
     wordLen = strlen(word);
     new = (char *) malloc(temp);
     //strlcpy(str, input, temp);

     strcpy(new, str);
     strLen = strlen(str);
    // if (word != NULL && str != NULL) printf("%s%d\n%s%d\n", word, wordLen, new, strLen);
     pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
     while (pch != NULL)
     {
       printf ("%s\n",pch);
       if(strcmp(pch,  word) == 0) count++;
       else printf("%s%s%d\n", pch, word, strcmp(pch, word));
       pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
       printf("(%s)\n",word );
      }

     //
     printf("Here is the output: %d\n",count);
     //n = write(newsockfd,"Result: %d\n",count, 18);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     free(str);
     free(input);
     free(new);
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);

     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code.

Comment: Can you post your actual code? It sounds like the trouble is in the communication, not in `strcmp()`.

Comment: Kindly have a look now.

Comment: Well, with the code this question is much better. You need learn how to code properly. You have too many lines in your main, use functions, declare variable only when you need it. All your code is unreadable. It's not a surprise that you can't find the bug with this kind of code.

Comment: @chux You are most likely right. `buffer[n]=0;` would suffice.

Comment: @DYZ thanks, it worked.Thank you for bearing with my code.So the end of string character was not passed by the client, right?

Comment: Looks like it was not sent. Hard to say without seeing the server code.

Comment: Does the client send a null byte at the end of the data?  If not (and most likely it doesn't), the server must add the null byte to the end of the data (converting it into a string) before trying to process the incoming data with string handling functions such as `strcpy()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Even if the null byte is sent there is no guarantee it is received along with the preceding data.

Comment: @clearlight Edit rejected. This is not '*The* Socket Tutorial'. This is *a* sockets tutorial. There are many. No reason to privilege this one above all the others, especially considering its basic flaws and primitive nature.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing weird here is that you are assuming that every `read()` results in an null-terminated buffer. It returns a read count. Use it.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use the read count for this problem?

Comment: Err, by not using methods such as `strcpy()` and `strcmp()` which assume a null terminator, and using the cognate methods which take a count instead?